# How to set all relationships of a certain type -- replacing the old ones if necessary -- in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have a node id for an event, and list of node ids for users that are hosting the event. I want to update these (:USER)-[:HOSTS]->(:EVENT) relationships. I dont just want to add the new ones, I want to remove the old ones as well.

NOTE: this is coffeescript syntax where #{} is string interpolation, and str() will escape any characters for me.

Right now I'm querying all the hosts:

```
MATCH (u:USER)-[:HOSTS]->(:EVENT {id:#{str(eventId)}})
RETURN u.id
```

Then I'm determining which hosts are new and need to be added and which ones are old and need to be removed. For the old ones, I remove them

```
  MATCH (:HOST {id:#{str(host.id)}})-[h:HOSTS]->(:EVENT {id:#{str(eventId)}})
  DELETE h
```

And for the new ones, I add them:

```
  MATCH (e:EVENT {id: #{str(eventId)}})
  MERGE (u:USER {id:#{str(id)}})
  SET u.name =#{str(name)}
  MERGE (u)-[:HOSTS]->(e)
```

So my question is, can I do this more efficiently all in one query? I want want to set the new relationships, getting rid of any previous relationships that arent in the new set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can achieve your objective in a single query by introducing `WITH` and `FOREACH`. On a sample graph created by

```
CREATE (_1:User { name:"Peter" }),(_2:User { name:"Paul" }),(_3:User { name:"Mary" })
CREATE (_4:Event { name:"End of the world" })
CREATE _1-[:HOSTS]->_4, _2-[:HOSTS]->_4
```

you can remove the no longer relevant hosts, and add the new hosts, as such

```
WITH ["Peter", "Mary"] AS hosts, "End of the world" AS eventId
MATCH (event:Event { name:eventId })<-[r:HOSTS]-(u:User)
WHERE NOT u.name IN hosts
DELETE r
WITH COLLECT(u.name) AS oldHosts, hosts, event
WITH FILTER(h IN hosts 
            WHERE NOT h IN oldHosts) AS newHosts, event, oldHosts
FOREACH (n IN newHosts | 
    MERGE (nh:User { name:n })
    MERGE nh-[:HOSTS]->event
)
```

I have made some assumptions, at least including

- The new host (`:User`) of the event may already exists, therefore `MERGE (nh:User { name:n })` and not `CREATE`.
- The old `[:HOSTS]`s should be disconnected from the event, but not removed from the database.
- Your coffee script stuff can be translated into parameters, and you can translate my pseudo-parameters into parameters. In my sample query I simulate parameters with the first line, but you may need to adapt the syntax according to how you actually pass the parameters to the query (I can't turn Coffee into Cypher).

Click [here](http://console.neo4j.org/r/8r8x8a) to test the query. Change the contents of the `hosts` array to `["Peter", "Paul"]`, or to `["Peter", "Dragon"]`, or whatever value makes sense to you, and rerun the query to see how it works. I've used `name` rather than `id` to catch the nodes, and again, I've simulated parameters, but you might be able to translate the query to the context from which you want to execute it.

**Edit:**

Re comment, if you want the query to also match events that don't have any hosts you need to make the `-[:HOSTS]-` part of the pattern optional. Do so by braking the `MATCH` clause in two:

```
MATCH (event:Event { name:eventId })
OPTIONAL MATCH event<-[r:HOSTS]-(u:User)
```

The rest of the query is the same.

Comment: I couldn't have asked for a better answer :)

Comment: I really need your help now because i dont know how all this works -- this doesnt appear to work if there are no hosts to begin with. In your example, I just added this at the top and it didnt work: `MATCH (u)-[x:HOSTS]->(e)
DELETE x`

Comment: @Chet I have added how to make the hosts part of the query optional.